# Accessing fields in nested structs

Tags: go

How do I reference a field in the "AllData" struct below from the main "Forecast" struct?  e.g if I wanted to reference "TemperatureMax from Forecast -> Daily?

```
type AllData struct {
    Time                       float64 `json:"time"`
    Summary                    string  `json:"summary"`
    Icon                       string  `json:"icon"`
    TemperatureMin             float64 `json:"temperatureMin"`
    TemperatureMinTime         float64 `json:"temperatureMinTime"`
    TemperatureMax             float64 `json:"temperatureMax"`
}

type HourlyData struct {
    Summary string        `json:"summary"`
    Icon    string        `json:"icon"`
    Data    []CurrentData `json:"data"`
}

type DailyData struct {
    Summary string    `json:"summary"`
    Icon    string    `json:"icon"`
    Data    []AllData `json:"data"`
}

type Forecast struct {
    Latitude  float64     `json:"latitude"`
    Longitude float64     `json:"longitude"`
    Timezone  string      `json:"timezone"`
    Offset    int         `json:"offset"`
    Currently CurrentData `json:"currently"`
    Hourly    HourlyData  `json:"hourly"`
    Daily     DailyData   `json:"daily"`
    Flags     Flags       `json:"flags"`
}
```

Comment: `DailyData.Data` is an array, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: hi - this mirrors the way the json feed is structured when you pull from forecast.io ( weather forecast). the goal is to eventually access any of the available variables in a fronted visualization. I can't print out any of the values in AllData at this point  e.g when using fmt.Printf

Comment: Can you include the JSON sample and how you are trying to use it with these data structures? That will help us provide more specific guidance.

Answer (score 4):

You can access an `AllData` field from a `Forecast` struct by providing an index into the `Data` slice in `DailyData`. Consider this stripped-down example of your question:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type AllData struct {
    Summary string
}

type DailyData struct {
    Data []AllData
}

type Forecast struct {
    Daily DailyData
}

func main() {
    a := AllData{"summary"}
    s := []AllData{a}
    d := DailyData{s}
    f := Forecast{d}

    val := f.Daily.Data[0].Summary

    fmt.Println(val)
}
```

In `main`, we read the `Summary` field from the `AllData` struct at index 0 of the `DailyData`'s `Data` slice. This prints `summary` to the console.

Optionally, we could access multiple `AllData` structs by ranging over the slice in `DailyData`:

```
func main() {
    a1 := AllData{"summary1"}
    a2 := AllData{"summary2"}
    a3 := AllData{"hello"}
    s := []AllData{a1, a2, a3}
    d := DailyData{s}
    f := Forecast{d}

    for _, val := range f.Daily.Data {
        fmt.Println(val.Summary)
    }
}
```

The above prints:

```
summary1
summary2
hello
```

Comment: Carl - this is great. the first option is closer to what I am looking to do - i.e access the variables in AllData individually ( vs. spitting it all out in a range like in the second option). However, this implies I have to setup variables like this for EACH item in AllData - and there are quite a few - I abbreviated it here for clarity.

Comment: I'm sorry then I don't really understand what you're trying to do, could you edit your question to specify what you mean beyond accessing the struct members?